# How to prefer Series over DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I'm select two columns from database table, and set one to index:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://localhost/air_base')
ts = pd.read_sql_query(
    'SELECT ModifiedDate, Value FROM stats', 
    engine,
    parse_dates=True, 
    index_col='ModifiedDate'
)
```

As a result I get DataFrame while I was expecting Series for some reason, as I have Datetime index and single column.

I was just wondering is there a way to instruct pandas to prefer series over dateframe as this is one thing that it seems it doesn't do automatically as it does nice with many other things.

Comment: does `read_sql_query` take an argument called `squeeze`? that might do it. otherwise, one workaround is `ts = pd.read_sql_squery(...)['Value']`.

Comment: Thanks. `read_sql_query` accepts just a few arguments, and no `squeeze`, but indexing on `['Value']` does the trick :)